# Mailer for Sharepoint (WSS 3.0)

Tags: wss-3.0

I want a simple Mailer for Sharepoint which can send & receive messages.

Is such a feature available?

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint has an API to send Emails.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx

Comment: Will I be able to send & receive messages in a List using the API ?

Comment: You need to configure the incoming mail settings in Central Admin before you can receive messages.

Sending emails from list items can be done from a standard Workflow in SharePoint Designer, or from the API within Visual Studio Workflows or even Event Receivers, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the ArgoSoft POP3 server.  It is very lightweight and is doing a really good job. You can find it here : [ArgoSoft Website](http://www.argosoft.com/rootpages/MailServerNetFree/Default.aspx).